# How to show a hidden item in a mapped element

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a React component that maps over images and outputs them onto the page. When each image is hovered, I want to display a hover menu over the top of the image only for that image. Currently, when one image is hovered, the menu shows in all the images on the page. Here is the current code I tried that doesn't work:

```
export default function Collection() {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(-1) 

  return (
    <div className='grid mv:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 px-24 gap-x-16 gap-y-52 place-items-center'>
      {collection.imageData.map((image, index) => {
        return (
          <Link
            href={`/illustrations/${id}/${image.url}`}
            key={index}
            className='relative cursor-pointer h-full flex items-center hover:border hover:border-[#DCDCDC] hover:shadow-lg ease-in duration-150'
            onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(index)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(-1)}
          >
            {isHovered && (
              <div className='h-full w-full z-90 bg-red-500 absolute top-0 left-0'>
                hi
              </div>
            )}
            <Image
              src={image.image}
              alt={`Vector ${image.alt} illustration`}
            />
            <p className='whitespace-nowrap text-center text-sm px-6 py-2 bg-white text-black border rounded-sm border-black absolute -bottom-24 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2'>
              Preview image
            </p>
          </Link>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to check that `isHovered` is equal to that index

```
{isHovered === index && (
   <div className='h-full w-full z-90 bg-red-500 absolute top-0 left-0'>
       hi
   </div>
)}
```

I'd change the name of that variable to `hoveredIndex` personally ‍♂️